# Hive Sql dynamically get null column counts from a table

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am using datastax + spark integration and spark SQL thrift server, which gives me a Hive SQL interface to query the tables in Cassandra.

The tables in my database get dynamically created, what I want to do is get a count of null values in each column for the table based on just the table name.

I can get the column names using `describe database.table` but in hive SQL, how do I use its output in another select query which counts null for all the columns.

Update 1: Traceback with Dudu's solution

> Error running query: TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0,
>   errorMessage="org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid usage of
>   '*' in explode/json_tuple/UDTF;", sqlState=None,
>   infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Invalid usage of '*' in explode/json_tuple/UDTF;:16:15",
>   'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation:org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute:SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:258',
>   'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation:runInternal:SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:152',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:257',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:388',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:369',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatement:CLIService.java:262',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:437',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1313',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1298',
>   'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
>   'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
>   'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617',
>   'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745'], statusCode=3),
>   operationHandle=None)

Comment: Does the table contain only "primitive" data types (integer, float, date etc.) or also complex data types (maps, structs, arrays etc.)?

Comment: primitive  data types only

Answer (score 4):

In the following solution there is no need to deal with each column separately.
The result is a column index and the number of null values in that column.
You can later on join it by the column index to an information retrieved from the metastore.
One limitations is that strings containning the exact text `null` will be counted as nulls.

#### Demo

The CTE (`mytable` as defined by `with mytable as`) can obviously be replaced by as actual table

```
with        mytable as 
            (
                select  stack
                        (
                            5
                            
                           ,1   ,1.2     ,date '2017-06-21'     ,null
                           ,2   ,2.3     ,null                  ,null
                           ,3   ,null    ,null                  ,'hello'
                           ,4   ,4.5     ,null                  ,'world'
                           ,5   ,null    ,date '2017-07-22'     ,null
                        ) as (id,amt,dt,txt)
            )

select      pe.pos                                          as col_index
           ,count(case when pe.val='null' then 1 end)       as nulls_count

from        mytable t lateral view posexplode (split(printf(concat('%s',repeat('\u0001%s',field(unhex(1),t.*,unhex(1))-2)),t.*),'\\x01')) pe

group by    pe.pos       
;
```

---

```
+-----------+-------------+
| col_index | nulls_count |
+-----------+-------------+
|         0 |           0 |
|         1 |           2 |
|         2 |           3 |
|         3 |           3 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I have added the traceback of the error that i get when running your query

Comment: This was tested on Hive. It seems like Spark doesn't like the combination of `posexplode` and `*`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of describe `database.table`, you can use

`Select column_name from system_schema.columns where keyspace_name='YOUR KEYSPACE' and table_name='YOUR TABLE'`

There is also a column called `kind` in the above table with values like `partition_key,clustering,regular`.

The columns with values as `partition_key` and `clustering` will not have null values.

For other columns you can use

`select sum(CASE WHEN col1 is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as col1_cnt,sum(CASE WHEN col2 is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as col2_cnt from table1 where col1 is null;`

You can also try below query (Not tried myself)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)-COUNT(col1) As A, COUNT(*)-COUNT(col2) As B, COUNT(*)-COUNT(col3) As C
FROM YourTable;
```

May be for above query you can create variable for count instead of count(*) everytime.

**Note:** `system_schema.columns` is cassandra table and cassandra user should have read permission to this table

Comment: I don't want to hardcode column names, because i have hundreds of tables

Comment: you will not have to hardcode it... read from `Select column_name from system_schema.columns where keyspace_name='YOUR KEYSPACE' and table_name='YOUR TABLE'` and make your select clause...

Comment: Yes how do I make that select clause without scripting language and only hive SQL, that is the question, I already have the column names using `describe database.table`